# Why does 'make' complain about a missing rule when I try to build a program from source?

Tags: compiling, make, source, mpi

I am a Linux novice, and I am attempting to compile scientific software called [DL_POLY_Classic](http://www.cse.scitech.ac.uk/ccg/software/DL_POLY_CLASSIC/index.shtml).  I downloaded the zip file **dl_class_1.6.tar.gz** and unzipped it using the command `tar xvzf dl_class_1.6.tar.gz`.  It gives me a series of folders containing various files for the program operation, which are described in the program [manual](http://www.cse.scitech.ac.uk/ccg/software/DL_POLY_CLASSIC/MANUALS/USRMAN.pdf).  One of these directories, called **source** contains many **.f** files, among other things.  The manual says that to compile the code, one needs to take one of the sample/template Makefiles and modify the paths therein to direct the `make` program to the appropriate directory containing the compiler.  (This DL_POLY_Classic program is written in, and must be compiled with, Fortran [Fortran 90, I believe].)

Based on the recommendation of a colleague, I am attempting to compile this code using an Intel Fortran compiler (ifort) that we have on our cluster.  I have modified one of the targets in the template Makefile; this target now has the following text in the Makefile:

```
#========== mpich-c2
mpich-c2: dpp
    cp /opt/mpich/ch-p4/include/mpif.h mpif.h
    $(MAKE) LD="/opt/mpich_intel/ch-p4/bin/mpif90 -O3 -o" \
    LDFLAGS="-L/opt/mpich_intel/ch-p4/lib64 -lmpich" \
    TIMER="" \
    FC=/opt/intel_fc_80/bin/ifort \
    FFLAGS="-c " \
    MPICH_F90="/opt/mpich_intel/ch-p4/bin/mpif90" \
    CPFLAGS="-D$(STRESS) -DMPI -P -D'pointer=integer'\
    -I/opt/mpich_intel/ch-p4/include" \
    EX=$(EX) BINROOT=$(BINROOT) $(TYPE)
```

I place the Makefile in the **source** directory, as the manual directs.  Then while in the **source** directory, I type the command:

```
make mpich-c2
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
cp /opt/mpich/ch-p4/include/mpif.h mpif.h
make LD="/opt/mpich_intel/ch-p4/bin/mpif90 -O3 -o" \
        LDFLAGS="-L/opt/mpich_intel/ch-p4/lib64 -lmpich" \
        TIMER="" \
        FC=/opt/intel_fc_80/bin/ifort \
        FFLAGS="-c " \
        MPICH_F90="/opt/mpich_intel/ch-p4/bin/mpif90" \
        CPFLAGS="-DSTRESS -DMPI -P -D'pointer=integer'\
        -I/opt/mpich_intel/ch-p4/include" \
        EX=D.X BINROOT=./ 3pt
make[1]: Entering directory `/export/home/myusername/dlc1_16/dl_class_1.6/source'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `dl_params.inc', needed by `angfrc.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/export/home/myusername/dlc1_16/dl_class_1.6/source'
make: *** [mpich-c2] Error 2
```

So, the `make` program is telling me that there is `No rule to make target dl_params.inc, needed by angfrc.o.`

My question is, what is the software telling me?  Is it likely saying that it cannot find a file **dl_params.inc**, or is it likely that it is saying that it cannot find a file **angfrc.o**?  Or, is it saying that I should have some sort of command in my Makefile to create a *new* file called **dl_params.inc**?

When I search in my Makefile (which, as I mentioned, is essentially exactly the template provided by the authors, but just with the directories in the `mpich-c2` target entries modified for the particular Fortran compiler to which I have access), I see only these mentions of **dl_params.inc**:

```
# Declare dependency on parameters file

$(OBJ_ALL): dl_params.inc
$(OBJ_RRR): dl_params.inc
$(OBJ_4PT): dl_params.inc
$(OBJ_RSQ): dl_params.inc
$(OBJ_NEU): dl_params.inc
$(OBJ_RIG): dl_params.inc
$(OBJ_EXT): dl_params.inc
$(OBJ_SPME): dl_params.inc
$(OBJ_HKE): dl_params.inc
```

I am not sure what this means.

On the other hand, when I search in my Makefile for **angfrc.o**, I see only one mention, in the first line of the following (after `OBJ_ALL`):

```
# Define object files

#=====================================================================

OBJ_ALL = angfrc.o bndfrc.o cfgscan.o corshl.o coul0.o coul4.o \
    coul2.o coul3.o conscan.o dblstr.o dcell.o diffsn0.o \
    diffsn1.o dlpoly.o duni.o error.o ewald1.o ewald3.o \
    exclude.o exclude_atom.o fldscan.o exclude_link.o forces.o\
    exitcomms.o extnfld.o fbpfrc.o fcap.o freeze.o gauss.o \
    gdsum.o getrec.o gimax.o gisum.o gstate.o images.o initcomms.o \
    intlist.o intstr.o invert.o invfrc.o jacobi.o lowcase.o lrcmetal.o \
    lrcorrect.o machine.o merge.o merge1.o merge4.o \
    npt_b1.o npt_b3.o parset.o npt_h1.o npt_h3.o nve_1.o \
    nvt_b1.o nvt_e1.o nvt_h1.o parlst_nsq.o parlink.o parlst.o passcon.o \
    passpmf.o pmf_1.o pmf_shake.o primlst.o quench.o rdf0.o rdf1.o \
    rdshake_1.o result.o revive.o scdens.o shellsort.o shlfrc.o \
    shlmerge.o shlqnch.o shmove.o simdef.o splice.o static.o strip.o \
    strucopt.o sysdef.o sysgen.o systemp.o sysbook.o sysinit.o \
    tethfrc.o thbfrc.o timchk.o traject.o vertest.o vscaleg.o \
    warning.o xscale.o zden0.o zden1.o \
```

I am not sure what this means, either.

Interestingly, when I use the `find` command to search by name--for example, `find -name angfrc.o`, `find -name *.o`, and `find -name dl_params.inc`--I can find nothing anywhere in the program directories with these names.  When I try `find -name *.inc`, I do find that a file **comms.inc** exists in the **source** directory.  This particular file says in its header that it is the "dl_poly include file for MPI, PVM and SHMEM."  It is a relatively short file (only 42 lines long), and it appears that it contains both "parameters for message tags" and "MPI tagsizes"--although, I do not really have a clue as to what I should be looking for in there.

If you have time, can you please give me advise as to what I should try next?  I am not so sure what the error message `No rule to make target dl_params.inc, needed by angfrc.o.` is telling me; do you have any ideas?  Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message `No rule to make target dl_params.inc, needed by angfrc.o.` means, that the Makefile specifies the file `dl_params.inc` as a dependency for the building of the file `angfrc.o`. So you have to somehow find or create the `dl_params.inc` file.

Searching the documentation indicates, that this file should contain FORTRAN parameters required by DL_POLY. The [user manual](ftp://ftp.dl.ac.uk/ccp5/DL_POLY/DL_POLY_CLASSIC/DOCUMENTS/USRMAN2.15.pdf) in section 7.1.1 explains, that there should be a `utility` sub-folder containing the program `PARSET` which can be used to generate such a parameter file (called `new_params.inc` by default).
You probably just have to rename the `new_params.inc` file to `dl_params.inc` and place it in the main source-folder.

If the error persists then the Makefile obviously expects the `dl_params.inc` file somewhere else and you would have to have a closer look at the Makefile.

Comment: The error message does not indicate that the file should be created by another rule - the build process might just as well expect it to be provided from somewhere else! If the Makefile does not have a rule for it then you have to either create the file manually (as specified in the documentation) or add the necessary steps to do so as a new rule to the Makefile. Since it is a somewhat niche program I would not be surprised that the build process requires some manual intervention (like creating a parameter file for your Fortran environment).

Comment: One more thing: it might of course also be that the file is specified by a rule in some other Makefile - maybe you should check with a recursive grep over the whole package tree if you find other (include) Makefiles that have a rule for `dl_params.inc`.

Comment: Another possibility is that the edited Makefile is broken (commands have to start with a TAB, not spaces; some editors "helpfully" expand TABs to spaces, or the user added a line starting with spaces that should have been a TAB).